# Finding a function from a big amount of values

Tags: functions

I have a big amount off y values. Example (1,65,4,98,543,543,678,4,2,7...). The x values would be (1,2,3,4,5...)I know that there is an infinite amount of functions fitting the points, but I only need one off them. Is there a method to find a function fitting all off the points? I need to be able to do it by myself and not to use a a program or app, because I need to know how it works.

Comment: The [Lagrange interpolation polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) will always work.

Comment: There are various methods of [interpolation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Interpolation.html) by which one can define values of a function for all the points between each pair of given $x$ values. You also have a choice of methods for how to determine the function values for inputs less than the least given $x$ or greater than the greatest given $x$; one way is just to continue the formula you used between the first two points or between the last two points. But whether any of these methods are OK for you depends on whether you have other constraints on what kind of function you can use.

Comment: What method generally gives the shortest functions ? If the function is longer than all points written behind each other it won't be useful for me.